# Black font on dark mode in my emails when I include my signature

Tags: html, css, email, signature, darkmode

I'm trying to create an HTML-CSS email signature.
But here is my problem : when I send from Apple Mail or receive emails on Apple Mail from Outlook web with the signature, it appears correctly even in dark mode, on the other hand in the body of the email (on which I am not supposed to have intervened!!) the text appears black even in dark mode, which makes it unreadable! I have very limited knowledge in HTML-CSS programming, I really don't understand where the problem comes from!

It seems that the font color problem is precisely caused by `<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark" />`
But I can't remove this meta tag since it's thanks to her that I solved a previous problem (my mails arrived with a white background even if the dark mode was activated).
I'm lost !

I also have another problem when sending email with signature from outlook web: my emails land in the recipient's spam folder. x_x

I so hope someone can tell me how to solve these problems!

Here is the result on Apple mail with text (black on dark mode !) above signature :

[image]

I attach my HTML, be indulgent I am a great novice.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
  <title>Signature</title>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG/>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
   :root {
      color-scheme: light dark;
      supported-color-schemes: light dark;
    }
    a {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body: {
      color: #ffffff
    }
  }
  </style>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
  <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark" />
</head>
<body style="font-family:'Barlow','Arial','Tahoma','Trebuchet','Helvetica','sans-serif'">
  <br/>
  <table role="presentation" class="darkmode" style="max-width: 350px ; padding: 15px">
    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse">
      <td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 0px ; padding-top: 0px ; padding-bottom: 0px ; margin:auto ; vertical-align:middle">
        <a href="https://www.siteinternet.blabla">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XjqZ6KZp/logo-hp-1024.png" alt="[LOGO]" title="Allé sur le site internet" width="50" style="width:50px">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px ; text-align: left ; line-height: 1.3 ; font-size: 10pt">
        <b>Jean Dupont</b>
        <br/> Marketing
        <br/>
        <a style="font-size: 9pt" title="Télécharger les coordonnées" href="https://qrco.de/">> Télécharger la fiche contact</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0px">
      <td colspan="3" style="height: 10px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:20px ; padding: 0px ; border-collapse: collapse">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="vertical-align:middle ; text-align: center; padding:3px; padding-left: 0px">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/gkWw93V6/mobile-RVB-2-PNG24.png" alt="•" title="Portable" width="10" style="width:10px">
      </td>
      <td valign="middle" style="font-size: 10pt">
        <a title="Téléphoner" href="tel:+33644444444">+33(0) 7 44 44 44 44</a>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:20px ; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>

      <td style="vertical-align:middle ; text-align: center ; padding:3px; padding-left: 0px">
        <img data-imagetype="External" src="https://i.postimg.cc/G3P7CGr6/old-phone-max30px-RVB.png" alt="•" width="13" style="width:13px" title="Fixe">
      </td>
      <td valign="middle" style="font-size: 10pt">
        <a title="Téléphoner" href="tel:+33455555555">+33(0) 4 55 55 55 55</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:20px ; padding: 0px ; border-collapse: collapse">
      <td></td>
      <td style="vertical-align:middle ; text-align: center ; padding:3px; padding-left: 0px">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Nf4z1TzR/mail-max30px-RVB.png" alt="•" title="Mail" width="12" style="width:12px">
      </td>
      <td valign="middle" style="font-size: 10pt">
        <a title="Envoyer un mail" href="mailto:machin@email.truc">machin@email.truc</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:20px ; padding: 0px ; border-collapse: collapse">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="vertical-align:middle ; text-align: center ; padding:3px; padding-left: 0px">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/s2XdBKfB/globe-max30px-RVB.png" alt="•" title="Site internet" width="13" style="width:13px">

      </td>
      <td valign="middle" style="font-size: 10pt">
        <a title="Visiter le site internet" href="https://www.siteinternet.blabla">www.siteinternet.blabla</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="padding: 0px ; border-collapse: collapse">
      <td colspan="3" style="height: 10px"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="height : 16px; padding: 0px ; border-collapse: collapse">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="vertical-align:middle ; text-align: center ; margin:auto; padding:3px; padding-left: 0px">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MTQLRFCG/location-pin-max30px-RVB.png" alt="•" width="9.6" style="width:9.6px" title="Adresse">
      </td>
      <td valign="middle" style="text-align: left ; padding-bottom:0; font-size: 10pt">
        <b>Compagnie</b>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr style="padding: 0px ; border-collapse: collapse">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="padding-top:0 ; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 9pt">
        <b>Agence Malibu</b>
        <br/> Zone industriel
        <br/> 110, rue des marguerites
        <br/> 32000 Marlou-les-bains

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your "This post" link currently refers to StackOverflow's start page.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You can refer to other discussions for clarity in cases where that might be appropriate, but your questions should always contain a proper example of what you are currently having problems with.